Narada Smriti and Dasas
Using this pdf Narada Smriti why does Narada Smriti authorize Dasas to rub and shampoo the master's body? Is this not lusty work?

I don't think the Smriti is authorizing it rather simply calling out what are considered to be unclean acts or ashubh karma (similar to the description of the eight types of marriages).

Yes, but it then states as per the translation these are the acts dasas preform
